# Is this limsup calculation correct?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

$a_n=1$ if $n=2^k$ for $k>0$

$a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$ otherwise

a) Find limsup $\displaystyle \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ - I think this is **infinity** because we can find a term that is 1/*something*!, but the next term will be 1, so the ratio will be *something*! which can be made infinitely large.

b) limsup $\displaystyle |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ - I think this is **1** because the maximum we can have is 1^1, rather than a fraction^1.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations for both are correct.  Congrats!